# Do axial film capacitors always connect to the center of their spiral?

Tags: capacitor

Are there axial film capacitors that connects to the outer edge of the spiral instead of the middle? Or both, even?

Comment: documented fairly well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_capacitor

Answer (score 2):

Axial Polystyrene capacitors often have their leads offset from the center, some appear to have them attached at the outside of the spiral.